How can I avoid props drilling in my React component?
I know this is a somewhat redundant question, but I'm facing a specific challenge in my React application that I hope someone can help with. I have a component that requires multiple props passed down from a parent component, and it's becoming increasingly complex to manage.
While I understand that there are alternatives like Context API or Redux for state management, in this case, not all states are shared among components, and it seems excessive to set up a global state for a single component. I still want to maintain good practices in my code.
Here's a snippet of my component:
<WorkPermitForm
  isMasterView={isMasterView}
  setIsMasterView={setIsMasterView}
  entryFormik={entryFormik}
  nameList={nameList}
  handleNameSelected={handleNameSelected}
  viewMode={viewMode}
  createMode={createMode}
  typeList={typeList}
  handleTypeSelect={handleTypeSelect}
  titleList={titleList}
  countryList={countryList}
  onCountryChange={onCountryChange}
  stateList={stateList}
  onStateChange={onStateChange}
  cityList={cityList}
  idCardList={idCardList}
  statusList={statusList}
  onUpload={onUpload}
  itemTemplate={itemTemplate}
  imageUrl={imageUrl}
  handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
  formData={formData}
  formRef={formRef}
  formik={formik}
  onVisitorTypeChange={onVisitorTypeChange}
  temporaryStateList={temporaryStateList}
  temporaryCityList={temporaryCityList}
  handleImageClose={handleImageClose}
  handleChange={handleChange}
  uploadRef={uploadRef}
  handleHyperlink={handleHyperlink}
  onUploadDocument={onUploadDocument}
  removeDocuments={removeDocuments}
  documentUrl={documentUrl}
  documentUploadRef={documentUploadRef}
  notification={notification}
  setBelongingDetailList={setBelongingDetailList}
  belongingDetailList={belongingDetailList}
  modeType={modeType}
  isCameraOff={isCameraOff}
  setCameraStatus={setCameraStatus}
  phoneNumber={phoneNumber}
/>

export const WorkPermitForm = (props) => {
  const {
    isMasterView,
    setIsMasterView,
    entryFormik,
    nameList,
    handleNameSelected,
    viewMode,
    createMode,
    typeList,
    handleTypeSelect,
    titleList,
    countryList,
    onCountryChange,
    stateList,
    onStateChange,
    cityList,
    idCardList,
    statusList,
    onUpload,
    itemTemplate,
    imageUrl,
    handleInputChange,
    formData,
    formRef,
    formik,
    onVisitorTypeChange,
    temporaryStateList,
    temporaryCityList,
    handleImageClose,
    handleChange,
    uploadRef,
    handleHyperlink,
    onUploadDocument,
    removeDocuments,
    documentUrl,
    documentUploadRef,
    notification,
    setBelongingDetailList,
    belongingDetailList,
    modeType,
    isCameraOff,
    setCameraStatus,
    phoneNumber,
    openDetails,
  } = props;

I'm looking for suggestions on how to restructure my component or use alternative patterns (like Context API or Redux) to manage state and avoid props drilling. What are some effective strategies or best practices for this?
I have this type of passing props in groups
  productDetails,
  pricingDetails,
  inventoryDetails,
  shippingDetails,
}) => {

  const {
    productName,
    productDescription,
    productImages,
    handleProductChange,
  } = productDetails;

  const {
    price,
    discount,
    currency,
    handlePriceChange,
  } = pricingDetails;

  const {
    stock,
    sku,
    handleStockChange,
  } = inventoryDetails;

  const {
    shippingOptions,
    selectedShipping,
    handleShippingChange,
  } = shippingDetails;

This is not efficient even in groups, i want to pass like an object to the component like
<WorkPermitForm
  workPermitProp={...workPermitProp}
/>


Have you considered the Composition Method? Note the link is old, but the technique is still applicable. You would no longer need to have groups of props to drill, you could create a Component at the top level passing in the required Props, and then rendering in the required position (Let me know if this is a helpful idea and you want a full answer)
